# Не скачивает файл до конца

Tags: curl, php

Процедура скачивания имеет такой вид:

```
self::$_curlDownload = curl_init();
curl_setopt(self::$_curlDownload, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt(self::$_curlDownload, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt(self::$_curlDownload, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt(self::$_curlDownload, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt(self::$_curlDownload, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_exec(self::$_curlDownload);
```

С помощью нее скачиваю картинки и трейлеры с кинопоиска.

Трейлеры (размер over 20мб) качает отлично.

А вот картинки (<1мб) скачивать особо не хочет, отваливается по тайм-ауту.

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с такой проблемой? Или хотя бы, куда копать, подскажите.

Выдержка из лога:

```
[23-12-14 15:01:00] Download error err_code#28 - Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 139557 out of 364458 bytes received
[23-12-14 15:01:00] Ошибка загрузки :http://st-im.kinopoisk.ru/im/poster/2/4/0/kinopoisk.ru-The-Matrix-Reloaded-2401204.jpg
```

Comment: Предположения:

 1. может, вы одновременно 1000 файлов тянете, а на их стороне стоит ограничение на одновременные подключения?
 2. может, это временный глюк на их стороне, или временный глюк канала между вашим сервером и целью?

На каких хостах у них лежат трейлеры — на тех же, что картинки?

Comment: @Sergiks
1. Тяну в 1 поток с паузой. И думаю если бы стояло бы ограничение на скачивание при попытке скачать я бы вылавливал status != 200
2. Возможно, благодарю за наводку.
3. Хосты разные